# How do I redirect to another page in JS / jQuery after sending a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I'm trying to make a JS script that works on the same form page. Everything works up until redirecting after a successful login.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#loginForm').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      url: 'goLogin.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      dataType: 'html'
    }).done(function(data) {
      $('#results').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $('#results').fadeIn('slow').html(data);
        window.setTimeout(function() {
          window.location.href = 'index.php';
        }, 5000);
      });
    }).fail(function() {
      alert('Error!');
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Try this location = 'http://www.google.com'; instead of window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';

Comment: Is the request sent? Are you sure it's returning a successful response? Any errors in the console?

Comment: @AbdulrehmanSheikh they are behaviourally identical

Comment: try with absolute path .. like http://localhost/index.php

Comment: @sathishkumar that wouldn't solve it, the issue here is that it isn't firing the redirect at all. I could understand if it was giving him a 404.

Comment: use `'./index.php'` instead of `'index.php'`

Comment: Is $('#results').fadeIn('slow').html(data); giving desired result?

Comment: Thank you all for your fast replies, AbdulrehmanSheikh it didn't work sadly
RoryMcCrossan yes, console is pretty clean nothing there and yes the other lines works properly.
sathishkumar I did, but it didn't work either.
Atul Sharma, the problem is that it isn't redirecting at all.
RK_15 yes they are.
Sorry I couldn't use @ to answer for some reason

Comment: @user1114748 put a log statement in setTimeout callback method and check if that callback function is executing or not

Comment: can you please replace done with success...and check the network tab...

Comment: @pixellab I did, but honestly I don't know how to analyze that window.
Console is still pretty clean, and it's still not working though

Comment: try window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com"; or window.location.replace

Comment: @user1114748 Are you sure, your setTimeout callback is executing?

Comment: @RK_15 Can you please show me how to do that?

Comment: @user1114748 replace code "window.setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("Getting executed");
          window.location.href = 'index.php';
        }, 5000);" and check the console for "Getting executed" string. Is it printing in console

Comment: replace        window.setTimeout(function() {
          window.location.href = 'index.php';
        }, 5000); by     setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href = 'index.php'; }, 5000);

Comment: @RK_15 ok so I changed "done" by "success" like pixellab said, and also added your code now I'm getting this
`````````````````````````
Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax(...).success is not a function
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (login.js:12)
    at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLFormElement.y.handle (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
`````````````````````````

Comment: @user1114748 No in your previous code only you have to put the log. Don't change success or done thing. And then check for console logs.

Comment: Sorry for the mess, didn't know code doesn't work in comments
I changed it back to done instead and I got  "getting executed"

Comment: @RK_15 Thank you for your assistance, the code pixel posted below got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'goLogin.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function(data){
    $('#results').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $('#results').fadeIn('slow').html(data);
        window.setTimeout(function() {
          window.location.href = 'index.php';
        }, 5000);
      });
    },
    error: function(data){
     alert('Error!');
}
});
```

Please check this code...Replace your ajax section...